# Error while installating YamCha Package

Tags: nlp, svm, pos-tagger

I try to install [YamCha](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/) tool for NLP tasks, like NER, POS, and chunking.

While trying to install, I followed the installation steps

```
% ./configure 
% make
% make check
% su
# make install
```

I got the following error messages:-

> param.cpp: In member function 'bool YamCha::Param::open(int, char**, const YamCha::Option*)':
>       param.cpp:102:42: error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope
>               size_t nlen = strlen (opts[i].name);
>                                                 ^
>       param.cpp:103:68: error: 'strncmp' was not declared in this scope
>               if (nlen == len && strncmp (&argv[ind][2], opts[i].name, len) == 0) {
>                                                                           ^
>       param.cpp: In member function 'bool YamCha::Param::open(const char*, const YamCha::Option*)':
>       param.cpp:182:28: error: 'strncpy' was not declared in this scope
>            strncpy (str, arg, 1024);
>                                   ^
>       param.cpp:185:12: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>        make  all-recursive
>       make[1](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/): Entering directory `/home/hamada/Documents/YamCha/yamcha-0.33'
>       Making all in src
>       make[2]: Entering directory`/home/hamada/Documents/YamCha/yamcha-0.33/src'
>       /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=CXX g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..     -O3 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -c -o param.lo param.cpp
>        g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -O3 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -c param.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/param.o
>            ptr[0] = PACKAGE;
>                   ^
>       param.cpp: In member function 'void YamCha::Param::help(std::ostream&, const YamCha::Option*)':
>       param.cpp:205:42: error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope
>              size_t l = 1 + strlen (opts[i].name);
>                                                 ^
>       param.cpp:211:38: error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope
>              size_t l = strlen (opts[i].name);
>                                             ^
>       make[2]: *** [param.lo] Error 1
>       make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hamada/Documents/YamCha/yamcha-0.33/src'
>       make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>       make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/hamada/Documents/YamCha/yamcha-0.33'
>       make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Do you have  header file `<string.h>` in your source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a header file missing in your code files. The link you provided above, contains a source file `src/common.h` , just add `#include<string.h>` in this file. With this addition, it should work.